# Must the two sets that equal to each other be elements of same set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In axiomatic set theory, two sets $A$ and $B$ are equal whenever $x \in A$ if and only if $x \in B$.

Then, for sets $A, B, C$ such that $A \in C$ and $A = B$, is it possible to prove that $B \in C$ with axioms of set theory?

Comment: The result follows by [Substitution axiom for equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms): $a=b \to ((z \in c)[a/z] \to (z \in c)[b/z])$

Comment: Thanks! I thought equality of sets is an undefined term but it has a definition in first order logic. I think that is why I misunderstood.